# Ubuntu. Blender crashes when opens Shader Editor

Tags: node-editor, linux

I haven’t been able to use the Shader Editor. Im using Blender 2.9.1. I have proved different versions and only works in my computer in Blender 2.69.

1- I open Blender 2.9.1 (empty project) 2-I switch to Shader Editor (Shift F3) 3- Blender crashes

This hapens with Cycles, Eevee and Workbench. Any suggestions?

PC info: Ubuntu 14.04 Intel core i7 7.7 Gb RAM Intel corporation 3rd Gen Core Graphics Controller (rev 09)

This is the crash log file of Blender:

```
Blender 2.90.1, Commit date: 2020-09-23 06:43, Hash 3e85bb34d0d7

bpy.context.space_data.context = ‘RENDER’ # Property
bpy.context.area.ui_type = ‘ShaderNodeTree’ # Property
backtrace

/snap/blender/47/blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x20) [0x81fdd40]
/snap/blender/47/blender() [0xe2329d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36cb0) [0x7f6f851e7cb0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2ea2fe) [0x7f6f6785d2fe]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e13f6) [0x7f6f678543f6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e1496) [0x7f6f67854496]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e07c8) [0x7f6f678537c8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e2c25) [0x7f6f67855c25]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2a7b45) [0x7f6f6781ab45]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e2178) [0x7f6f67855178]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2a7b45) [0x7f6f6781ab45]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e12ca) [0x7f6f678542ca]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e076c) [0x7f6f6785376c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2a7b45) [0x7f6f6781ab45]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2eb3fa) [0x7f6f6785e3fa]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x423131) [0x7f6f67996131]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x37b1e0) [0x7f6f678ee1e0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x21823e) [0x7f6f6778b23e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x1308ea) [0x7f6f676a38ea]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_shader_create_ex+0x687) [0x6f1a7a7]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_shader_create+0x12) [0x6f1b032]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_shader_create_from_arrays_impl+0xb7) [0x6f1b0f7]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_shader_get_builtin_shader_with_config+0x1c2) [0x6f1b772]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_batch_program_set_builtin_with_config+0xd) [0x6f03b9d]
/snap/blender/47/blender() [0x184275c]
/snap/blender/47/blender(nodelink_batch_end+0x28) [0x1843d98]
/snap/blender/47/blender(node_draw_nodetree+0x11d) [0x184781d]
/snap/blender/47/blender() [0x1847967]
/snap/blender/47/blender(drawnodespace+0x449) [0x1847dc9]
/snap/blender/47/blender(ED_region_do_draw+0x811) [0x1487631]
/snap/blender/47/blender(wm_draw_update+0x4da) [0x10deb5a]
/snap/blender/47/blender(WM_main+0x30) [0x10dcab0]
/snap/blender/47/blender(main+0x317) [0xd5ec67]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f6f851d2f45]
/snap/blender/47/blender() [0xe1fa83]
Python backtrace
```

The new log file, after updating the graphic drivers (blender now crashes befor oppening), is here:

```
# Blender 2.90 (sub 0), Commit date: 2020-04-15 14:32, Hash debd8aab4a82

# backtrace
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x1d) [0x697e3fd]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender() [0xc12bef]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36cb0) [0x7f73661d7cb0]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(GPU_uniformbuffer_update+0x3) [0x5699d93]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(workbench_update_material_ubos+0x53) [0x105aff3]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(workbench_cache_finish+0x1e4) [0x1020164]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender() [0xff83bb]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(DRW_draw_render_loop_ex+0x221) [0xffa6d1]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(view3d_main_region_draw+0x8f) [0x16064bf]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(ED_region_do_draw+0x8f1) [0x121bc91]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(wm_draw_update+0x52d) [0xec030d]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(WM_main+0x30) [0xebe2f0]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender(main+0x321) [0xb49811]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f73661c2f45]
/home/ginko/Descargas/blender-2.90-debd8aab4a82-linux64/blender() [0xc0f41c]
```

Comment: Try the official version from [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/) and not the snap install. Repositories, flatpack, snap and other distributions are done by third parties, and sometimes miss libraries or create different incompatibilities.

Comment: The crash occurs in the graphics driver. You may want to update it, if you're able to. However 14.04 may not have the most recent ones available in its repository.

Comment: Hello @susu, I have tried that way but it apperars the same problem. Then I tried tu update the graphic drivers, as suggented @ Robert Gützkow, (following this instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/645080/intel-graphic-drivers-for-ubuntu-14-04) but now, blender crashes before oppening. Im adding the new crash log in the original question.

Comment: Is your integrated GPU really fulfilling the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)? If yes, then I would suggest you create a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/).

Comment: I was searching intensively these days and found that no one had this problem. After updating the blender drivers directly it never worked again. So my desperate solution was to install the operating system. In an hour I was working with blender again without problems.

I also thank you both for trying to help me. These forums are very important to me and I always find solutions to my problems just by reading user questions. So, thanks a lot!